# How do I use Google Apps Script to extract data from a JSON file on Google Drive and push the array into a table in Google Sheets?

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am **new** to coding and have set myself a goal.

The goal has four parts:

1. Extract iOS Reminders from my iPhone using Shortcuts
2. Transform the resulting JSON file in Google Apps Script
3. Load the data into a table in Google Sheets
4. Present the reminders in an insightful way.

At this juncture, I can view the array in Google Apps Script using this code:

```
function getFileContent() {
  var fileName = "Reminders.json";
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    Logger.log(json);
  }
}
```

My execution log returns the array in this format:

```
{reminders=[{list=Personal, task=Learn how to code, date=31 Dec 2021}, {...}, {...}, {...}]}
```

The notation "..." refers to additional reminders embedded in the array.

I need help using Google Apps Script to transform the JSON file into a table of data in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to make a 2d-array from your JSON. It can be done this way:

```js
var jsn = {'reminders':[
        {'list':'Personal', 'task':'Learn how to code', 'date':'31 Dec 2021'}, 
        {'list':'Personal', 'task':'Learn how to code', 'date':'32 Dec 2021'}, 
        {'list':'Personal', 'task':'Learn how to code', 'date':'33 Dec 2021'}, 
    ]};

var array = jsn.reminders.map(x => [x.list, x.task, x.date]);

console.log(array);
```

Then you need to put the 2d-array on your sheet. Something like this:

```
function json_to_table() {
  var jsn = {
    'reminders': [
      { 'list': 'Personal', 'task': 'Learn how to code', 'date': '31 Dec 2021' },
      { 'list': 'Personal', 'task': 'Learn how to code', 'date': '32 Dec 2021' },
      { 'list': 'Personal', 'task': 'Learn how to code', 'date': '33 Dec 2021' },
    ]
  };

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // set table headers
  var headers = [Object.keys(jsn.reminders[0])]; // get the keys from the first reminder
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,headers[0].length);
  range.setValues(headers); // put the keys into a first row of the table

  // set table body
  var body = jsn.reminders.map(x => [x.list, x.task, x.date]);
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,body.length,body[0].length);
  range.setValues(body);

}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update**

The full implementation could look like this:

```
function getFileContent() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Reminders.json");
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var json    = JSON.parse(files.next().getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headers = [Object.keys(json.reminders[0])];
    var body    = headers.concat(json.reminders.map(x => [x.list, x.task, x.date]));
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, body.length, body[0].length).setValues(body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yuri – very helpful! I seem to be missing the step that enables me to work with my data extract from the JSON file. How do I link the code in my question to your code above?

Comment: I've added the full implementation to my answer. It's shortened but it does exactly the same.

Comment: Almost there! This script successfully transforms my JSON file into a 2d-array and adds headers to the Google Sheet (i.e. without the data below them). Execution halts on the last line, with error message: "Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues." Can you recommend any changes?

Comment: My bad. There should be `.setValues(body)`

Comment: All good. I am still seeing the same error message. The script runs all the way through if I set it to `.getValues()` with a 'g' and no 'body' though does not push any data to Google Sheets. Any other ideas?

Comment: I've changed `headers + json...` with `headers.concat(json...` Try it. Python like concatenation of arrays with `+` doesn't work in Javascript :)